A question about distance function to a submanifold in complete riemannian manifold.
Let $\left(M, g\right)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold. Fix a properly embedded submanifold $N$ of $M$ and consider the distance function $r(x) := \operatorname{dist}(x, N)$.
On the other hand, as $M$ is complete, we can restrict the exponential map onto normal bundle $T^{\perp}N$, that is, map $\exp^{\perp}:T^{\perp}N\to M$.
Now suppose $\exp^{\perp}$ is a diffeomorhism from an open subset of $T^{\perp}N$ to an open subset $U$ of $M$. Then we can define a function $r'$ on $U$ such that $r'(x):=|{\exp^{\perp}}^{-1}(x)|$. We can see that when $x$ is close to $N$, $r(x)=r'(x)$, but does this holds for all $x\in U$? If this is not the case, then under what conditions can it be true?

After considering the case when $N$ is a point $p\in M$, I find this is wrong in general, even when $U$ is a neighborhood of $N$. A counterexample is when $M$ is the cylinder, consider $\exp_p: T_pM\to M$ and a neighborhood $V$ in $T_pM$ as in the following picture (the black lines draw the boundary of the segment domain):

Then we can see $\exp_p$ is a diffeomorphism on $V$, but clearly $r'$ is not the distance function when outside the segment domain.
So I guess that's why we should consider a concept similar to the segment domain, that is, a maximal neighborhood of $N$ where $r=r'$ holds.

It's basically the same story as when $N$ is a single point. The definitions of conjugate and cut points have straightforward generalizations, and the same theorem holds: A geodesic is minimizing up to the first conjugate or cut point. The proof is also essentially the same.

@Deane thank you for your comment! I'll try to follow this way to prove it.

Please feel free to post questions if you run into any difficulties.
